# Sorting strings that have partial similarity PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to sort strings that have partial similarity but different as a whole.

e.g.

```
$array = ["ABC1002", "ABC1001", "X001BAC", "X001ABC"];
```

I want to sort this array according to alphabetical order first. If it is similar e.g. "ABC.." or "X001.." then I will sort by "...1001", "1002" and "...ABC", "BAC".

```
$array = ["ABC1001", "ABC1002", "X001ABC", "X001BAC"];
```

Sorry if my explanation is not clear.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Read documentation for natural sort function

Comment: Does the natural sort check the front part and sort in alphabetical order as well as shown in my example? e.g. "ABC..." and "X001" @emix

Comment: Of course, try and test

Comment: Thanks Thanh Trung, emix and Ferdy Pruis. Tried natsort() and it worked well. Thanks for the quick response.!

Answer (score 1):

This is called "natural sort" and is implemented as natsort()

```php
natsort($array);
```

> This function implements a sort algorithm that orders alphanumeric strings in the way a human being would while maintaining key/value associations

Answer (score 0):

Have to apply natsort — Sort an array using a "natural order" algorithm https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

```
natsort($temp_files);
echo "Natural order: ";
print_r($temp_files);
```